# AntPathRequestMatcher is not matching string with wildcards

Tags: spring, glob

I have a SpringBoot application and want to detect the liveness endpoint being invoked so I can allow the request to be unauthenticated.

When I make this request:

```
http://localhost:8080/001/MyApp/actuator/health/liveness
```

The code below prints `false`.

Shouldn't `new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**liveness")` cause `isWhitelisted` to return `true`?

```
public RequestMatcher getRequestMatcher() {
  return new OrRequestMatcher(
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/error"),
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login**"),
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**logout"),
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**liveness"));
}

public boolean isWhitelisted(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
  return getRequestMatcher().matches(httpServletRequest);
}
```

```
System.out.println(requestPropertyResolver.isWhitelisted(httpServletRequest));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed this instead:

```
return new OrRequestMatcher(
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/error"),
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login**"),
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**logout"),
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/liveness"));
```

`/**/` - matches zero or more 'directories' in a **path**, so needed to end the directory tree